# overriding virtual function covariant return types (both pointers)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to override a base class function. Both the derived type and the base type return pointers so it should be covariant according to some posts I read on google and here on stackoverflow..

However in MSVC2013 for the following classes:

```
class PSBaseObject
{
    public:
        PSBaseObject() {}
        virtual ~PSBaseObject() {}

        virtual void* data() { return this; }
        virtual const void* data() const { return this; }
};

template<typename T>
class PSObject : public PSBaseObject
{
    private:
        T* data_;

    public:
        PSObject(T* object) : data_(object) {}
        ~PSObject() { delete data_; }

        T* data() { return data_; }
        const T* data() const { return data_; }
};
```

I get an error:

```
'PSObject<data>::data': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'PSBaseObject::data'
```

Where data is defined and used as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    void* hFileMap;
    void* pData;
    std::size_t size; 
} data;

data* info = new data();

auto ptr = new PSObject<data>(info);
```

Why is it not covariant?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in `MSVC2013`? The code compiles and works fine in `g++ 4.8.1`.

Comment: `void*` is not covariant with `T*` -- the error is clear?

Comment: If that were true, why does it compile and run with g++: http://ideone.com/TwTBRQ

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Because g++ is failing to follow the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case gcc is wrong, and VS is right in rejecting the code. The standard treats this in 10.3/7, where it defines what *covariant* means. That definition requires that both return types are pointers or references to *classes*. Since `void` is not a class, the code you present does not show *covariance*.

Gcc is wrongly accepting the code.

Answer (score 5):

MSVC is right; `void*` is not covariant with `T*`. Quoting from the standard (10.3 [class.virtual], section 7):

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden
>   function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, the
>   return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> — both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
>   classes
>
> — the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D::f`, or is an
>   unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
>
> — both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f`
>   has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of `B::f`.

`void` is not a base class of `T` (= `data`), so the return types are **not** covariant.

---

So why this rule? Well, the idea is that if you have

```
struct B {
    virtual U* f();
};

struct D : B {
    virtual V* f();
};

B* b1 = new B();
B* b2 = new D();
U* u1 = b1->f();
U* u2 = b2->f();
```

`b1->f()` is going to call `B::f`, which returns `U*`. But `b2->f()` is going to call `D::f`, which returns `V*`. `V` must be derived from `U` so that the `V*` returned from `D::f` can always be converted to `U*`.

Now, it is **reasonable** to allow `U` to be `void` in this case, because any pointer to object type can be converted to `void*`, even though `void` is not a base class of anything. But the standard does not require that it be allowed.

The standard also says (1.4 [intro.compliance], paragraph 8),

> A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.

So g++ is not *wrong*. Allowing `U` to be `void` is an *extension* which does not alter the behaviour of any well-formed program, and g++ *does* issue a warning when you try to compile this code.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that gcc is not strictly wrong, as this can be considered an extension.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC2013 is right.

When you will call

```
  ptr->data();
```

Compiler will not know what method to use, it could be `PSBaseObject::data()` or `PSObject<data>::data();`

So you need to fix your design.

Comment: But it does know (g++ knows?). The function is virtual. It will call the child class's data function. If it doesn't exist, it calls the base class's: http://ideone.com/TwTBRQ So which compiler is right here?